# Can you make a full clone of Winforms ComboBox.ObjectCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to filter out certain items in my winforms combo box. I have a piece of code that obviously does not work since the assignment makes a pointer/reference copy not a deep content copy. I think I am probably using the wrong approach here, there might be better solutions. But my exact question is: How can I make a full clone object of my combobox items and work with it? Is that not possible?

```
        ComboBox.ObjectCollection tmpItems = comboBoxKey.Items;
        comboBoxKey.Items.Clear();
        String tmp2 = textBoxSearchKey.Text;
        foreach (object o in tmpItems) //tmpItems has no objects here since it is cleared
        { 
            String tmp1 = o.ToString();
            if (tmp1.IndexOf(tmp2) > 0)
            {
                comboBoxKey.Items.Add(tmp1);
            }
        }
```

By the way, many times it is convenient that the C# language protects us from pointers. But in this case, if you'd have worked with C or C++, it at least was clearer what was going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var tmpItems = comboBoxKey.Items
            .Cast<Object>()
            .ToArray();
comboBoxKey.Items.Clear();
String tmp2 = textBoxSearchKey.Text;

var filteredItems = tmpItems.Where(x=> x.ToString().Contains(tmp2))
                            .ToArray();
comboBoxKey.Items.AddRange(filteredItems );
```

Comment: Thanks! All suggestions are good and informative. Yours was the closest to the things I was trying to do, hence I choose that as official answer. But also thank you Tarec and Neo

Answer (score 1):

It is clear what's goind on under the hood. Once you're completely unreferencing an object, you treat it as if it would not exist. There's no need for deep copying here, just copy the data references you want to new collection before clearing the source one.

```
var newItems = new List<string>();

   foreach (object o in comboBoxKey.Items)
    { 
        String tmp1 = o.ToString();
        if (tmp1.IndexOf(tmp2) > 0)
        {
            newItems.Add(tmp1);
        }
    }
comboBoxkey.DataSource = newItems;
```

And whatever you want to do, you could do it in 1 line with LINQ query

```
comboBoxKey.DataSource = comboBoxKey.Items.Where(i=>i.ToString().IndexOf(tmp2)>0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Object base class to catch the Items collection from combobox. And then loop it
like List tmpItems = comboBoxKey.Items.ToList();